# Orphan/lost data when renaming a property

Tags: properties, blend-files

I'm registering a property to the grease pencil:

```
bpy.types.GreasePencil.old_property_name = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyCustomClass)
```

I've decided to refactor/rename that property, and and with that, all files have lost their data on that property. What can I do to link that old data to the new property?